# Have setup Transport Security in my app but still encountered error message

Tags: swift2

in My project , I have setup the below in info.plist

I understand that below is for the WebServer does not support HTTPS

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Question:

1) If my app calls a webserver which support Https, do I need to use above App Transport Security setting?

2) If my app call the 1st WebServer (Proxy server) which does not support Https and this Proxy server call the Actual webserver that support https. do I need to set up the App Transport Security settings?

3) If this proxy server in (2) support Https. What I need to do?

I dont know if Webserver that my App is calling support HTTPS  and I am getting this error message

KCFStreamErrorDomaininSSL, -9843

What I need to do?

When I place the URL into the WebBrower , I got this error msg:

Your connection is not secure

The owner of www.XXXXXXX.com has configured their website improperly. 
To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. 
As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

Thanks

Comment: `has configured their website improperly` Your issue is not on the client side, it's on the server side.

Comment: @Eric, I just edit my post. which scenario reflect my case? I think I call the proxy server first. Is that means the Proxy server doing it intentionally? Or the problem will go away once they configure correctly?